# Selection of D.C. Motor for hand-cranked generator

Tags: dc-motor, generator

I'm a college student working on an independent engineering project. We are using a D.C. Motor as a generator. It's going to be hooked up to a circuit with capacitors and an LED assembly to store and discharge the electricity. The final product has to weigh 225g or less and be around ~165cm cubed at most.

Does anyone have any insight or advice on D.C. Motor selection? Do the voltage and RPM ratings on these small motors hold any useful information when using it as a generator? Also, has anyone ever tried modifying a small motor by using stronger stator magnets, installing a larger brush coil, or changing the gearing?

Any advice is helpful, thank you!

Comment: Check out motors used in r/c toys as the weight limit precludes larger stuff...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does anyone have any insight or advice on D.C. Motor selection?

For reference, an average cyclist should be able to keep up about 150 watts continuously. (125 W for an eight-hour shift is 1 kWh - the amount of work you can get out of a servant in a day.) I imagine that with a bench mounted generator and two hand cranks that about half of that could be generated. If the generator is to be held in one hand and cranked with the other I would imagine that 20 W would be difficult. All of the above should help in selection of your generator *power* rating (W or watts).

> Do the voltage and RPM ratings on these small motors hold any useful information when using it as a generator?

Yes. The motor datasheet or nameplate should specify the voltage rating and no-load speed. e.g., 12 V, 5,000 RPM. If you crank the motor at 5,000 RPM you should get close to 12 V out. (There will always be some losses that prevent it being a perfect motor or generator.) The voltage will scale linearly with speed so cranking at 2,500 RPM will give 6 V out.

Gearbox selection will be determined by working out the maximum speed of hand-cranking. I'd say that 3 revs/s = 180 RPM would be quite fast. The gearbox ratio is simply the desired motor speed / hand speed. Note that the gearbox will also absorb some energy.

> Also, has anyone ever tried modifying a small motor by using stronger stator magnets, installing a larger brush coil, or changing the gearing?

I'm sure someone has but this will be difficult. The magnets will be curved and probably glued into place so removal will be difficult and replacement with the tight tolerances required will be difficult. Rewinding the armature would be interesting and instructional but you have to terminate the enameled wire correctly at each armature contact segment. I think you will find it difficult to match an industrial manufacturer's quality.

Quick feasibility tests:

[image]

*Figure 1. A bike hub generator. Source: [VIK Approved](https://vikapproved.wordpress.com/2013/08/05/shimano-dynohub-dh-3n80-1-yr-review/).*

Borrow a bike wheel with built-in generator. Mount the wheel in a bench vise, run wires back to the bike lamps and spin the wheel by hand. Note the difference with lights disconnected and connected. These are typically rated at 3 W. You can measure the voltage and current and calculate the power. Note that these are AC so "alternator" is the correct term although "dynamo" is the popular term but this implies DC.

[image]

*Figure 2. Wind-up generators are available for radio and battery charging. Source: [Windup Battery](http://www.windup-battery.com/radio).*

If you can find any of these in a store you might get a feel for the amount of energy required to do some useful work.

Comment: I bet that wind-up radio weighs in at more than 225g ....

Answer (score 0):

Note that the RPM and operating voltage is the central feature of PM DC motors/generators.

If you know that a 6V DC motor runs at 6,000RPM with no load, then when used as a generator, spinning it at 6,000RPM will produce 6VDC.   That's ideally, if we ignore the slowing caused by bearing-friction and air viscosity.    And also, spinning it at 5000RPM will output 5VDC, 1000RPM will output 1VDC, etc.   For permanent-magnet motors, voltage and RPM are directly proportional.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, very much appreciated. With this information in mind, I ordered a larger variety of 24V motors with a variety of RPM ratings as well as some extra 12V's. I think that implementing a D.C. D.C. converter correctly in the circuit will add performance. Time for lots of testing.